# add month to curent date in aqua data studio

Tags: sql, db2, aqua-data-studio

I am trying to develop a report through aqua data studio by using SQL.I am trying to extract report of last month like counting the total number of new users in the last month. Date_Creation is the column when a user is registered in the system. I have tried DATEADD("MONTH",-1,Current_Date) but getting error "Month is invalid in context" .Any Solution/Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

DB2 doesn't use DATEADD for date arithmetic, you just, err easier to show.

SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE_CREATION > CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a `MONTH`, why are you trying to "add" a "date" (which is what I assume `DATEADD` might mean)?  What does it mean to add two `DATE`s together? I.e. what is the result of '2019-01-01' + '2019-01-01' ?!

Anyway, I digress. You can use `ADD_MONTHS` if you wish https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053628.html

or, use the `- 1 MONTH` solution, which is just as good (if not better)